# How to start MySQL with skip-partition?

Tags: mysql, centos, partitioning

I would like to start MySQL server with skip-partition in CentOS to partition. How can I start it? I saw a option about to start when compiling from source. I installed mysql with rpm.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html This might help you

Comment: empty result return when I run **show variables like 'have_partitioning';**

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_partition

Comment: Why?  I ask because there may be another way to solve the _real_ problem.